# Using Dictionary to get right "command"

Tags: c#, dictionary

Code example below. So I want to execute if statement. How can I do it by iterating dictionary? "stop" and "end" should have same meaning and their value is 2.

```
Dictionary<string, int> commands = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    {"start", 1},
    {"stop", 2},
    {"end", 2}
};

string input = Console.ReadLine();
if (input.Equals(STOP or END)) 
{
    //Do this
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use a for-loop or foreach-loop on the key collection. That one can be explicitly extracted.

Comment: For example commands.TryGetValue()

Comment: It is very unclear what you want to do. The only thing that I can help you is to change `input.Equals(STOP or END)`  to `input == STOP || input == END`.

Comment: if ( commands.ContainsKey( input.ToInvariantLower() ) ) might be a start for you?

Comment: Thanks @kenny , the problem is next that if i have multiple values in dictionary, they all react to it.

Comment: If you have additional issues not included in the original question, you should either edit the question or ask a new one.

Comment: @rtuomas String has some issues, but matching to often is not one of them. You need extra functions to get halfway intuitive matching behavior half the time. With those values you must not actually be checking against the key.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would iterate over a dictionary and check for your commands

```
Dictionary<string, int> commands = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    {"start", 1},
    {"stop", 2},
    {"end", 2}
};

foreach (var key in commands.Keys)
{
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (key == "start" || key == "stop") 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do what you have to do here");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over a `Dictionary` using `foreach`.
But from what I understand of your question I think the following will work:

```
Dictionary<string, int> commands = new Dictionary<string, int>()
        {{"start", 1}, {"stop", 2}, {"end", 2}};

string input = Console.ReadLine();

if (commands.ContainsKey((input.ToLower())))    // this checks if the input is equal to any of the keys present in the Dictionary
{
    if (input.ToLower() == "end" || input.ToLower() == "stop")
    {
                // do this
                // you can also get the value from Dictionary by key here
    }
}
```